# How can I make a .toggleClass button click keep its effects on different pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been developing a site which makes use of a button to toggle it's whole appearance between positive & negative themes for the background/navbar/text color, depending on what the user prefers. I've done the home page with a simple toggleClass method:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.switchButton').click(function(){
         $('.mainBg').toggleClass("bg-inv");     
     });
 });
```

How can I make it so that when the user loads any other page of the website, it will open with the theme chosen previously (as in, if the page you're in is on negative, all of them will be negative until you change to positive)? I plan to insert a switch on every single page, but having to flick it every time you'd want to use the second theme is very annoying. I'd thought about an IF jquery function, but am not sure how to use it between different pages.

Comment: Use a cookie to save the preference

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is stateless. This means that data between connections is not saved, and every request is a fresh one based on the code on the server.

If you want to save data across requests, you will have to save it in a place that is not dependent of the request. This can be either in a in a cookie, a session variable, in a database or you can use localstorage.

You can only access the cookie from JavaScript directly, so that would be your easiest bet.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the value in a cookie and load it in each page so that it persists between pages.

Answer (score 1):

On Home page you can store the value in sessionStorage and on every page you can retrieve the value from sessionStorage variable.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('.switchButton').click(function(){

          $('.mainBg').toggleClass("bg-inv");
          sessionStorage.class = "bg-inv";

    });     
});
```

On every page you can check the variable

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
          $('.mainBg').addClass(sessionStorage.class);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

let's assume you make a variable called `class;` . Now in the toggleClass function write `class=a` where `a` is the variable you pass to toggleClass, bg-inv in this case.  Now you can save `class` in your localStorage by `localStorage['class'] =class` and retrieve it whenever required using `localStorage['class']` or `localStorage.getItem('class')`  Hope this helps!